# 3 way transaction deadlock in mysql innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

If innodb detects a 3 way deadlock, would it report on all the involved transactions in the "LAST DEADLOCK DETECTED" section of "show engine innodb status" ?
Also when innodb reports a deadlock, why doesn't it ever report the locks TRANSACTION (1) holds?
It reports locks TRANSACTION (1) is waiting for,
It reports locks TRANSACTION (2) is holding,
It reports locks TRANSACTION (2) is waiting for.
Why not that one?

Thanks,
Vivek